# c# mvvm proper event disposal

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

I have implemented MVVM pattern in my WPF windows. I have a subwindow which I call the following way (from another ViewModel):

```
cmd_Show = new DelegateCommand(
    (sender) =>
    {
        frm_Strediska _window = new frm_Strediska();
        frm_StrediskaViewModel vm = new frm_StrediskaViewModel(ZakladneStrediska, _window);
        _window.DataContext = vm;
        _window.Owner = App.Current.MainWindow;

        _window.ShowDialog();
    });
```

Here under `frm_StrediskaViewModel` I hook to a `Window.Closing` event in a following way:

```
public frm_StrediskaViewModel(ObservableCollection<DefaultStrediska> _Strediska, frm_Strediska _Window)
{
    Window = _Window;
    Strediska = _Strediska;

    InitializeCommands();

    Window.Closing += Window_Closing;
    }
```

The thing I am not sure about is, that when I close this SubWindow, if my `Window.Closing` event unhooks automatically, or I have to override `Dispose()` event on the ViewModel (that's what I am doing now):

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    Window.Closing -= Window_Closing;
    this.Dispose();
}
```

Is this a good approach, or is it completely unnecessary?

Comment: The view model should not know the view by reference. It should only communicate with it via data binding. Event handlers should be placed in the code-behind.

Comment: @poke, how about event in general: is it necessary to unsubscribe any subscribed event in `Dispose()`?

Comment: An object A should unsubscribe from another object B’s events when A is removed. But when B is removed, the reference to the handler is also garbage collected. So you usually don’t need to unsubscribe from events handled within the same type, or events of types that have a shorter life time. And for a control, you wouldn’t use `Dispose` but rather the [`Unloaded`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.unloaded.aspx) method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to do this with neat bindings, but it requires the Blend SDK. You need the `System.Windows.Interactivity.dll` for this. The first thing required is to add the namespace declaration:

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
```

With this import you gain the possibility to bind commands to events like so:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
  <i:EventTrigger EventName="Closing">
    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding CloseCommand}" />
  </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Adding this to your window will cause the command bound with `CloseCommand` to be executed once the `Closing`-Event is raised by the window.

So you  don't need to do any binding to the event yourself. You can just create the required property in your ViewModel that returns the command. This command has to do what ever is required during the closing. So basically what you got in your event handler currently.

```
public readonly ICommand CloseCommand
{
  get { return /* Your closing command here */; }
}
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: This doesn't really answer his question.\

Comment: The question was answered by the comment to the question by @poke. This answer gives a alternative way to handle cases like this according the MVVM pattern.